# Nested tuple extractor in scala ->

Tags: scala, tuples, extractor

Is there a convenient extractor that is the reflection (in mathematical sense) of the `->` operator?

For example, this works:

```
scala> val y = 1 -> 2 -> 3
y: ((Int, Int), Int) = ((1,2),3)

scala> y match { case ((a,b),c) => s"Values are : $a, $b, and $c" }
res0: String = Values are : 1, 2, and 3
```

But this doesn't:

```
scala> y match { case a -> b -> c => s"Values are : $a, $b, and $c" }
<console>:9: error: not found: value ->
              y match { case a -> b -> c => s"Values are : $a, $b, and $c" }
                                    ^
<console>:9: error: not found: value a
              y match { case a -> b -> c => s"Values are : $a, $b, and $c" }
                                                            ^
```

You can see how this would be useful when you have a number of nested tuples. In case you're wondering, my nested tuples are produced by an external library, so I can't just 'flatten' y myself.

Comment: The link @johny provided has the answer. But I just wonder, is there any reason why do you prefer `1 -> 2 -> 3` over `(1, 2, 3)`? If you use `1 -> 2 -> 3` you will still see from time to time `((1, 2), 3)` (in output or in debug), and it looks ugly

Comment: @johny yes this is exactly the same question. Thanks.

Comment: @Archeg, as I said in the question, it's because I'm getting this from an external library in that form...

Comment: sorry, missed that. You can though flatten tuple with shapeless: https://github.com/milessabin/shapeless/blob/master/examples/src/main/scala/shapeless/examples/flatten.scala It might be better than keeping this weird tuple form

Answer (score 0):

Try next

```
scala> y match { case ((z01,z02),z2) => println(s"$z01 -> $z02 -> $z2") }
1 -> 2 -> 3

scala>
```

Comment: What I'm trying to avoid is the nested parentheses after the `case`, which you're still using. If you have a level of nesting of 5, for example, you would have to write `(((((z0,z1),z2),z3),z4),z5)` , which is a mess. instead I want to do `case z0 * z1 * z2 * z3 * z4 * z5 => `, where `*` is some binary operator.

Comment: Do not use tuples in this case. Transform you structure to tree like set of `case classe`s.